# Warnings when upgrading project from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4.0.1

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4

I was working with Xcode 3.1.3, and all my projects were working fine with zero warnings.  Today I upgraded Xcode to 4.0.1, and now my projects are running, but I am getting 70-80 warnings. Is there any way to upgrade our code so that it will work fine with Xcode 4.0.1?

Comment: Do you have an example of what those warning are?

Comment: ya like UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated,sendind "some class name" to parameter of incompatible type id<NSXMLParserDelegate>

Comment: directoryContentsAtPath is deprecated

Comment: Xcode 4.0.1 comes with the latest SDK, therefore you need to update your code to use the latest methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's giving you more warnings is because with Xcode 4 the default complier was switched over from GCC to LLVM.  The result is more verbose and helpful warnings *(and better detection of problems in the first place)*, which is why you see a ton more than before.  Try not to ignore them, instead I would read them carefully and try to fix what it's telling you.

Comment: Yup. The way to upgrade your code is to go through the list of issues and fix each one, one at a time. Yes, it'll probably take awhile. You need to do it anyway; just because the compiler wasn't complaining before doesn't mean it wasn't a problem then, and even if it wasn't (because, say, the method wasn't deprecated before), it is a problem now.

Comment: Exactly what Peter said.  In addition, it never hurts to turn on "treat warnings as errors", then you're forced to fix them.  :)